# PHP Multidimensional Array return error

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array called $reads when I do an var_dump($reads), I get the below array result.
I am trying to get first item of first array with var_dump($reads[0][0]). I get a Message: Error rendering view: [home.uploaded] Undefined offset: 0

```
array(161) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["517a5745e8505"]=>
    string(29) "Ngee Ann Poly_Keywords report"
    ["517a5745e86fe"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["517a5745e882e"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["517a5745e89b5"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["517a5745e8505"]=>
    string(7) "Keyword"
    ["517a5745e86fe"]=>
    string(6) "Clicks"
    ["517a5745e882e"]=>
    string(11) "Impressions"
    ["517a5745e89b5"]=>
    string(3) "CTR"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["517a5745e8505"]=>
    string(18) "accounting diploma"
    ["517a5745e86fe"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["517a5745e882e"]=>
    string(3) "364"
    ["517a5745e89b5"]=>
    string(5) "0.55%"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["517a5745e8505"]=>
    string(11) "polytechnic"
    ["517a5745e86fe"]=>
    string(4) "1940"
    ["517a5745e882e"]=>
    string(5) "42995"
    ["517a5745e89b5"]=>
    string(5) "4.51%"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(4) {
    ["517a5745e8505"]=>
    string(15) "tourism diploma"
    ["517a5745e86fe"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["517a5745e882e"]=>
    string(3) "156"
    ["517a5745e89b5"]=>
    string(5) "0.64%"
  }
```

Comment: what does var_dump($reads[0]["517a5745e8505"]); give?

Comment: `var_dump($reads[0]["517a5745e8505"]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var_dump($reads[0]["517a5745e8505"]);
```

for what you want as per comments do this, put you array in a $arr variable and follow what I am doing.

```
$firstelementvalues = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($arr as $key=>$val) {

        $x = 0;
        foreach ($val as $value) {
            if ($x == 0) {
                $firstelementvalues[] = $value;
                $x = 1;
            }

        }

        $i++;
    }

print_r($firstelementvalues);
```

Output is

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Ngee Ann Poly_Keywords report
    [1] => Keyword
    [2] => accounting diploma
)
```

Comment: Otherwise foreach is the option with key, in his case he just wanted to know the value of first element of array, that is what I understood hence replied accordingly

Comment: Actually I am trying get all the first item of each array

Comment: Check my updated answer you do what I have done and you will get final result of first element of each array into a final array. Just put your array into a variable $arr and then copy paste my code it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no value in array with 0 offset so please try like

```
var_dump($reads[161][0]);
```

Comment: neither is 0 in second dimension ;)

Comment: @nicogawenda I missed that in this answer i was focused on 161! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to use loop (for,foreach) if you would like to display AND use the data. 
var_dump is: Arrays and objects are explored recursively with values indented to show structure.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your array doesn't have element `[0][0]`.

If you want to select first element in second dimension array you can use [current](http://php.net/current):

```
$lev1 = current($yourArray);
$lev2 = current($lev1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your reads array has no numeric keys in the second dimension. You could do something like this, if you have no clue about the keys:

```
$read = $reads[0];
// I am getting all keys now, because I guess you also want to process the rest of that data
$readKeys = array_keys($read);
var_dump($read[ $readKeys[0] ] );
```